# Outputting new arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to produce an array by drawing data from two separate databases. I am getting close, but right now the data is output as one string: e.g.

```
[Smith, [ED-100,Some ClassED-200,Some Other Class]]
```

I would like the data to be in the form

```
[Smith, [[ED-100,Some Class], [ED-200,Some Other Class]]]
```

I have been spending hours fiddling with the code, but seem to have  come up short. Here is what I have:

```
  var teacherzCourses = [];
  var teacherz = Object.getOwnPropertyNames(uniqTeach).sort();
        for (var j = 0; j < teacherz.length; j++) {
                var tName;
                var tCourses = [];
    for (k = 0; k < registrarData.length; k++) {
      Object.getOwnPropertyNames(uniqTeach).sort();

      // get the courses each teacher does
      for (var j = 0; j < teacherz.length; j++) {
        tName = teacherz[j];
        tCourses = [];
          tempArray = [];
        for (k = 0; k < registrarData.length; k++) {
          if (registrarData[k].Teacher.indexOf(teacherz[j]) > -1) {
            console.log([teacherz[j], registrarData[k].CourseNum, registrarData[k].CourseName]);
            tCourses += [registrarData[k].CourseNum, registrarData[k].CourseName];
          };
            tempArray += (tCourses);
        };
        teacherzCourses.push([tName, tCourses]);
      };
    };
    console.table(teacherzCourses);
    console.log(teacherzCourses[0][1]);
  };
```

I have the feeling I am making this much more complicated than it needs to be.

Comment: Arrays don't have a `+=` operator.  So, when you're doing that, it's forcing a type conversion.  If you want to add an item onto the end of an array, use `array.push(newItem)`.

Comment: That is so strange -- I could have sworn I tried that and it didn't work. It does now. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Change this line:

```
tCourses += [registrarData[k].CourseNum, registrarData[k].CourseName];
```

to this:

```
tCourses.push([registrarData[k].CourseNum, registrarData[k].CourseName]);
```

As *jfriend00* mentioned, there's no `+=` operator on arrays.